# Inserted row in PostgreSQL are not available in trigger function

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpython

- database : postgresql
- language : plpythonu
- topic: trigger function

```
create trigger request_received_trigger 
   after insert on req_table  
for each row 
execute procedure request_received_function();
```

I need to do something after every insert but the inserted record dose not appear in queries that I make inside `request_received_function()`. Is inserted record locked inside trigger function?

1. trigger fires well and I can debug it
2. on the second insert record is show itself

Comment: You need to show us the code for the trigger function `request_received_function()`. Why do you make queries inside that function? Are you aware that you can access the inserted row using the `new` record inside the function? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: Just any select query on req_table, The problem is that queries returns all but the inserted record. And Yes I have access to record through TD['new'] rv = plpy.execute("SELECT * FROM req_table")

Comment: Again: show us the code, this works for me:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/801bf/1 Btw: are you sure you want a *row* level trigger if you are selecting from the table? That sounds like a **lot** of overhead. Wouldn't a statement level trigger be more efficient?

Comment: if you count the number of records you will see that you are always one behind. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7d355/2